# How to debug custom mule 4 SDK connector?

Tags: mule, mule-studio, mulesoft

I have a custom mule 4 SDK connector, I want to debug runtime and design time.

Answer (score 1):

Just select **Connect Java Debugger** checkbox in `Window -> Preferences -> Anypoint Studio -> Debugger`

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Just connect a Java debugger to the JVM. The connector is Java code.

Answer (score 0):

**To debug runtime:**

Go to your Anypoint Studio, open "Run Configurations", select your Mule project from "Mule Applications" on the left (you need to run it at least once for it to appear here). Then in the "Arguments" tab add to the VM arguments:  `-Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=y,address=1044` - this will enable to attach to your debugger from the IDE you use for SDK development.

In your IDE add a **debug config** with connection type "Socket Attach", provide host (localhost) and port (1044).

Now you can set breakpoints in your IDE then start the Mule project in Anypoint Studio. When it is at the point of launching the runtime JVM (watch the Console) it will stop and wait for you to start the debug config set above and execution shall hit your breakpoints.

**To debug design-time:**

Go to where you installed Anypoint Studio, find `AnypointStudio.ini`
Add following contents after the `-vm plugins` line:

```
-vmargs
-Xdebug
-Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=y,address=8888
```

also uncomment following two lines near the end, so they look like this:

```
#To_debug_the_mule_instance_uncomment_the_following_line
-Dmule.tooling.debug=true
#To_specify_the_debug_port_for_the_design_time_mule._E.g._To_debug_connectors_code_at_design_time.
-Dmule.toolingInstance.debugPort=8000
```

In your IDE create two "Socket Attach" type debug config, for localhost and ports 8888 and 8000.

Start Anypoint Studio. It will wait for you to start the debug config for port 8888, then it will come up. A minute later start the debug config for port 8000 - this is the one attaching to the design-time JVM. You can watch the threads starting in the Debug perspective of your IDE.